how using jdbc driver with java modules
I am programming a database application in Java and would like to use java modules.
The following code crashes with an error:

package dm;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
      final String dbUrl =
         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://server/database";

      try {

         final Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "user", "password");
      } catch (final SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

as module-info.java I use:
module sandbox2 {

   exports dm;
   requires java.sql;
}

When I run this code, I get the following error message
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-17858: JNDI package failure: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not resolve a valid ldap host
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17858/
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:1615)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1137)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1178)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:105)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:886)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:693)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
        at sandbox2/dm.App2.main(App2.java:18)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-17858: JNDI package failure: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not resolve a valid ldap host
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17858/
        at oracle.net.jndi.JndiAttrs.initializeLDAPContext(JndiAttrs.java:310)
        at oracle.net.jndi.JndiAttrs.<init>(JndiAttrs.java:165)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.<init>(AddrResolution.java:406)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.<init>(NSProtocol.java:247)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.<init>(NSProtocolNIO.java:148)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1000)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not resolve a valid ldap host
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getContextFromEndpoints(LdapCtxFactory.java:187)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.lambda$getUsingURL$0(LdapCtxFactory.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:570)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:195)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:241)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:160)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:90)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
        at oracle.net.jndi.JndiAttrs.initializeLDAPContext(JndiAttrs.java:295)
        ... 12 more

If I delete module-info.java the code runs without errors, but I want to use java moduls. Does anyone know how to specify the jdbc driver correctly in module-info.java or does anyone have another solution? I include the jdbc driver with a maven build file:
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
         <version>23.4.0.24.05</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>

Thanks
changed jdbc driver version, hoped resolves the problem, but didn't

Does adding requires java.naming; help?

Your IDE such as IntelliJ should help by suggesting changes to the module-info.java file.

By the way, DataSource. And oracle.jdbc.datasource.

@Slaw too bad, the addition of requires java.naming did not help, thanks

Is the SQLException the root cause? Or are there Caused by after it?

@Slaw Here are the Caused by: Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-17858: JNDI package failure: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not resolve a valid ldap host
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17858/
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not resolve a valid ldap host

@BasilBourque Eclipse did not help

Post your additional details as edits to the Question, not as Comments.
